# How to use Ruby 2.6.6 when rbenv can't find it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I created a new Rails app (v5.2.4.3) using Ruby 2.7.1 and discovered the blizzard of "keyword parameter" warnings endemic in this release.

`rbenv install --list`, for some reason, doesn't list Ruby versions beyond 2.4.0. I've manually installed 2.6.6 but am unable to launch it.

This seems like a simple problem. Hints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should firstly check the version of plugin 'ruby-build':

```sh
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git log
```

If you have not `~/.rbenv/plugins` directory, maybe it is too old for the version of your rbenv. First update rbenv:

```sh
cd ~/.rbenv
git pull
```

Then install 'ruby-build' plugin:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Comment: my .rbenv directory contains /shims, /version and /versions subdirs. 2.7.1. is the only version listed.
I'm using rbenv v1.0.0.

Comment: Instead of the rbenv's version, it is the plugin 'ruby-build'. You should go to the directory `~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build` and execute command `git log` to check.

Comment: (see previous answer.)
~/.rbenv/plugins does not exist.

Comment: Ok, make some changes of my answer, see above.

Comment: Perfect - this did the trick. My previous install must have been a simple download - not a Git pull. Props.